# What to insert data into 2 tables in a single hit

Tags: java, mysql

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryBuilder.toString());
pstmt.setString(count++, commonDTO.getGroupName());
pstmt.setString(count++, commonDTO.getSubGrpNameHindi());
pstmt.setString(count++, commonDTO.getGroupCode());
pstmt.setInt(count++, commonDTO.getIsActive());
pstmt.executeUpdate();

StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
queryBuilder = queryBuilder.append(SLCMQueryConstant.Get_SubGrp_Id);
pstmt.setString (1, commonDTO.getGroupName());
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
int x = 0;
while(rs.next())
{
    x= rs.getInt("subject_Group_ID");
}

queryBuilder= queryBuilder.append(SLCMQueryConstant.MapSubject_to_SubGrp);
pstmt.setInt(count++, x);
pstmt.setInt(count++, commonDTO.getSubGrpID());
pstmt.setInt(count++, commonDTO.getSubjectMaxMark());
pstmt.setInt(count++, commonDTO.getSubjectMinMark());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
```

I am trying to insert a new row into first table.then I want id of newly added 
row and insert into 2nd table but there is an exception.

Comment: It would help if you would show both the queries you are running and the error message you are getting.

Comment: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery(). is the exception I m geeting .I m trying to execute 3 queries in a single trasaction

Comment: INSERT INTO m_subject_group_master (SubjectGroup_Name,SubjectGroup_Name_Hindi,SubjectGroup_Code,Is_Active) VALUES(?,?,?,?);    select subject_Group_ID from m_subject_Group_mater where subjectGroup_Name=?   ..INSERT INTO m_Subject_subjectgroup_map (subject_Group_ID,subject_Id,Max_Mark,Min_Mark) VALUES(?,?,?,?)

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what's wrong - executeQuery is for executing SELECT queries, not INSERTS/UPDATES. Use `executeUpdate` instead, as e.g. described [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0002).

Seeing you have added your query above - to execute multiple queries, run multiple executeQuery / executeUpdate statements. As long as you don't have auto-commit set and commit the third query, all three queries will be executed as a single commit (i.e. cannot be interrupted).

It is ***not possible*** to run multiple queries with a single executeQuery / executeUpdate, separated by semicolon. This syntax is simply what many clients use to separate queries textually, but the clients will send these queries separately with multiple requests as well.

I'd guess that running three separate queries in a single transaction will be exactly what you need. However, if for some reason you absolutely want to do it with a single execute, you can use a [stored procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure), which you prepare ahead of time.

Comment: I want to execute select statement thats why I am using executeQuery.In this  1st I am inserting into one table.then I m selecting that id of newly inserted row.then I am trying to insert that id into second table

Answer (score 0):

You have to create prepared statements from your built queries:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryBuilder.toString());
pstmt.setString(count++, commonDTO.getGroupName());
pstmt.setString(count++, commonDTO.getSubGrpNameHindi());
pstmt.setString(count++, commonDTO.getGroupCode());
pstmt.setInt(count++, commonDTO.getIsActive());
pstmt.executeUpdate();

StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
queryBuilder = queryBuilder.append(SLCMQueryConstant.Get_SubGrp_Id);
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryBuilder.toString());  // <<<<<<-----
pstmt.setString(1, commonDTO.getGroupName());
Recordset rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
int x = 0;
while(rs.next())
{
    x = rs.getInt("subject_Group_ID");
}
```

And you have to reset your prepared statement parameter counter:

```
queryBuilder= queryBuilder.append(SLCMQueryConstant.MapSubject_to_SubGrp);
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryBuilder.toString());  // <<<<<<-----
count = 1; //<<<<<-----
pstmt.setInt(count++, x);
pstmt.setInt(count++, commonDTO.getSubGrpID());
pstmt.setInt(count++, commonDTO.getSubjectMaxMark());
pstmt.setInt(count++, commonDTO.getSubjectMinMark());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
```